# center one div float th

Tags: html, css-float, center

I am trying to learn how to create two divs within a container div. I would like the divs within the container to sit side by side with one centered (with respect to a header) and the other floated right.

You can see here:  http://jsfiddle.net/mariabarrette/KjvZA/3/

I would like the "main" div to be centered wrt the header, and for the "sidebar" to float right.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You want the div "maincontent" is centered while the div "sidebarinfo" is to the right of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you put your sidebar div before the main div and you set the auto margins, it should work ok.  Provided you have enough room to fit both div on the enclosing div width.  See http://jsfiddle.net/KjvZA/16/ (but not registered, so might not last).

Comment: thank you, that worked. unfortunately, the content in the page im working on is no longer contained within the "main" border. This does not happen in the jsfiddle and I assume it is related to something else in my coding. Any guesses as to what it might be? Or solutions as to how I can fix that?

Comment: Is this content within the main div or inside a subordinate div? Did you add any other style elements to it? Which browser do you use? Is the behaviour the same with different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you did most of it already. if i'm understanding you correctly, this should do it:

1. Remove text-align:center; from the "container" div
2. SEt the width of the header to:     width:285px; (same as the content).

is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried that but it is not giving me the result I want. When I follow the instructions above, it causes the "main" div to center wrt the header but the "sidebar" div then moves and sits under the "main". I would like the "main" div and "sidebar" div to remain side by side but for "sidebar" to sit on the right side while "main" is centered.